# GDIPlus::Bitmap Brightening Image c++

Tags: c++, image-processing, gdi+

The aim of the following function is to get the R,G,B values of each pixel from a Bitmap loaded from file and increase them by 10.

```
void PerformTransformation(Gdiplus::Bitmap* bitmap, LPCTSTR SaveFileName) {
    Gdiplus::BitmapData* bitmapData = new Gdiplus::BitmapData;
    UINT Width = bitmap->GetWidth();
    UINT Height = bitmap->GetHeight();
    Gdiplus::Rect rect(0, 0,Width,Height );
    bitmap->LockBits(&rect, Gdiplus::ImageLockModeRead, PixelFormat32bppARGB, bitmapData);


    byte*  pixels = (byte*)bitmapData->Scan0;
    INT iStride = abs(bitmapData->Stride);

    for (UINT col = 0; col < Width; ++col)
        for (UINT row = 0; row < Height; ++row)
        {

            unsigned int curColor = pixels[row * iStride / 4 + col];
            int b = curColor & 0xff;
            int g = (curColor & 0xff00) >> 8;
            int r = (curColor & 0xff0000) >> 16;            
            if ((r + 10) > 255) r = 255; else r += 10;
            if ((g + 10) > 255) g = 255; else g += 10;
            if ((b + 10) > 255) b = 255; else b += 10;

            pixels[curColor & 0xff ] = b;
            pixels[curColor & 0xff00 >> 8] = g;
            pixels[curColor & 0xff0000 >> 16] = r;

        }

    bitmap->UnlockBits(bitmapData);             
    CLSID pngClsid;
    GetEncoderClsid(L"image/png", &pngClsid);
    bitmap->Save(SaveFileName, &pngClsid, NULL);    
}
```

However when checking the save file, the brightness has not increased. I have tried to increase the values to update each R,G,B value to be 100 each but the image remains the same, Seems like i'm not setting the new values correctly.

Can anyone show me what im doing wrong?

EDIT: 
After following some guidance i now have the image brightening but only brightening a quarter of the image.

[image]

Changed Code

```
void PerformTransformation(Gdiplus::Bitmap* bitmap, LPCTSTR SaveFileName) {
    Gdiplus::BitmapData* bitmapData = new Gdiplus::BitmapData;
    UINT Width = bitmap->GetWidth();
    UINT Height = bitmap->GetHeight();
    Gdiplus::Rect rect(0, 0,Width,Height );
    // Lock a 5x3 rectangular portion of the bitmap for reading.
    bitmap->LockBits(&rect, Gdiplus::ImageLockModeWrite, 
PixelFormat32bppARGB, bitmapData);

    byte*  Pixels = (byte*)bitmapData->Scan0;
    INT stride_bytes_count = abs(bitmapData->Stride);
    UINT row_index, col_index;
    byte pixel[4];
    for (col_index = 0; col_index < Width; ++col_index) {
        for (row_index = 0; row_index < Height; ++row_index)
        {

            unsigned int curColor = Pixels[row_index * stride_bytes_count / 
 4 + col_index];
            int b = curColor & 0xff;
            int g = (curColor & 0xff00) >> 8;
            int r = (curColor & 0xff0000) >> 16;
            if ((r + 10) > 255) r = 255; else r += 10;
            if ((g + 10) > 255) g = 255; else g += 10;
            if ((b + 10) > 255) b = 255; else b += 10;


            pixel[0] = b;
            pixel[1] = g;
            pixel[2] = r;
            Pixels[row_index * stride_bytes_count / 4 + col_index] = *pixel;
        }
    }



    bitmap->UnlockBits(bitmapData);     
    ::DeleteObject(bitmapData);
    CLSID pngClsid;
    GetEncoderClsid(L"image/png", &pngClsid);
    bitmap->Save(SaveFileName, &pngClsid, NULL);    
    }

};
```

Comment: Remove the 3 lines starting with `pixels[...]` and replace them with a single line starting `pixels[row*iStride/4+col]= r | (g<<8) | (b<<16)`

Comment: You asked for PixelFormat32bppARGB, good idea, but that makes a pixel 4 bytes, not 1 byte.  So you must address it with `UINT*`, not `byte*`.

Comment: Ah thank you, however now ive changed that the image is always black when saved any ideas?

Comment: Because you're setting alpha to zero. You need to copy alpha to pixel[3]. Also, your code is horribly ineffective, but maybe speed doesn't matter and then it's of course OK.

Answer (score 0):

- You never check return codes.
- You access bitmap data in reading mode (Gdiplus::ImageLockModeRead)
- You are indexing pixel channel values by color value pixels[curColor & 0xff]
- You never delete allocated bitmapData object

Comment: Hi thanks, Will Change now! also How should i be indexing pixel channel values in this case?

Comment: Define pixel as an array of byte [4], and deal with pixel iterator which should be incremented after each pixel write (to move to next pixel) and after each stride end (to move to the first pixel of the next stride).

Comment: Is Variable row my Pixel iterator in this case?

Comment: Each stride contains array of `width` pixels plus (potentially) some extra padding totaling to `iStride` bytes. I think you are getting confused because your variable names are misleading, for example `iStride` should be `stride_bytes_count`, `row` should be `row_index` and so on.